# What is causing my rubymine test results runtime to be in days?

Tags: ruby, ide, cucumber, capybara, rubymine

The project I work on is ruby BE, react FE, with end to end tests written in capybara/cucumber.

Due to some configuration file or something I'm guessing, when I run the tests, the output states several hours per test and I'm not sure where this is coming from, any ideas?

[image: RubyMine test results pane]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a known problem in RubyMine:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-28351/Timing-seems-off-when-running-Cucumber-test

Please add your vote there specifying also the IDE's version.